# Feature Class relate with table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, modelbuilder, table, feature-class

I use ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop.

I have a polygon Feature Class with municipalities.

In a non-geographic table, I have these same municipalities, with an additional contract information.

The contract name is stored as a String in a field. Each municipality can have either zero, one or more contracts. In the table it appears as often as it has the information, i.e. a municipality with three contracts appears three times in my table.

At the end, I need a dissolved polygon for each contract where every munipality of the specific contract is within. These polygons must be overlapping when a municipality has more than one contract.

Does anyone have any idea how to to this, preferably in ModelBuilder, that another user could reuse it, only pointing where he has the existing table and feature class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ArcMap, here's an example of municipalities:

[image]

And a table:

[image]

Initiate a join on the municipalities polygon feature class by right-clicking on it in the table of contents:

[image]

Join by municipality fields and `keep all records`:

[image]

Export the polygon feature class to a new feature class:

[image]

The new feature class will have a polygon per contact:

[image]

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for your answer, but I cannot get it working. With this join it keeps only the first contact per municipality even if I have selected "keep all records". So if I have 1300 municipalities before, it stays at 1300 polygons and some got a contact, and some did not because they do not have one.
I have a 1 : n relation, and ArcMap only gets me a 1:1 join without dublicating the polygons for the number of needed contacts.

Comment: Did you export after joining?

Comment: At first I did, it did not work. But now it is OK! Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I'm glad to help.

Comment: How can I get the same result using ModelBuilder? As join does not function within a geodatabase...